# C# return data for logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Im using ASP.Net Core 3 with membership.  Currently I have the index method returning all entries in the Assets table.  I want to change it so that it returns Assets based on the logged in user while allowing the Administrator role to view all of them.

In the Assets table I have a column where the User ID gets stored for each user who creates a new Asset.  I'm not sure which way to go with this with what I already have.

**Controller Code**

```
public ViewResult Index() {
    // retrieve all the assets
    var model = _assetRepository.GetAllAssets();

    // Pass the list of assets to the view
    return View(model);
}
```

**Respository Code**

```
public IEnumerable<Asset> GetAllAssets() {
    return context.Asset;
}
```

**Interface Code**

```
public interface IAssetRepository {
    Asset GetAsset(int Id);

    IEnumerable<Asset> GetAllAssets();
    
    Asset Add(Asset asset);
    Asset Update(Asset assetChanges);
    Asset Delete(int Id);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to start is following one of the tutorials around working with authentication and authorization in ASP.NET Core. [Here's one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1) that seems to address your case.

Comment: I checked that out before coming here.  The problem with that and other examples is that is still pulls in all data and limiting edit / delete functions to the logged in user.  I need to show data only the user created in a list.  I also need to be able to work with the code above.

Comment: @oscararango That link should work for you. Once you have authenticated the user, then use the `context.User.UserID` and filter the assets based on that.

Answer (score 0):

First at all, I recommend you to add a new column that keeps the "role". If you don't want to use the framework that already does that. Then if you add a column with the role you can do on the repository something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Asset> GetAllAssets(Guid userId) {
    var role = context.Asset.Where(x => x.userId = userId).Select(x => x.role);
    if (role = "admin")
       return context.Asset;
    return context.Asset.Where(x => x.userId = userId);
}
```

For this case I hardcode "admin" you can replace with your implementation. But I think you want to arrive to a solution like this...

I hope to help you. And I recommend you to add a new layer "service", between the controller and the repository, you can add there the "business logic".